# Trying to use CreateProcess() ; no compiler errors but main keeps crashing

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a function which opens a PDF in firefox separate from the main process. I believe I am having trouble with the parameters for createProcess... any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: the batch file is being created, I have tested it several times, and to explain a bit:
The batch file is because I really don't know what I am doing, I am a student in computer science and this is a side project to help me at my job. I work at a law office and file the mail electronically as it comes in. I wanted to make a simple program that would loop through the scans directory, display the scan and prompt the user for information about the document. Therefore I need to be able to build a file path dynamically. Originally I was using "system" to open firefox and display the document. After a bit of trying I got it to work with a batch file. I then learned that system is a blocking command and that I would need to start a separate thread. This is where I ran into createprocess. I simply continued to use the batch file from my old system idea... And the more I think about it I can't remember which professor suggested the batch file or why...

```
void openPDF(char scansQueue[][MAX_NAME], int index)
{
// build bat file
fstream outfile;
outfile.open("C:\\firefox.bat");    
if(outfile.good())cout<<"outfile good!!!!"<<endl;
outfile<<"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" \"C:\\Scans\\"   <<scansQueue[index]<<"\"";

STARTUPINFOW si; 
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; 
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
if(!CreateProcess(NULL, L"C:\\firefox", NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))cout<<"PROCESS FAILED TO EXECUTE!!!";
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

}
```

Comment: Side Note: The crash is because CreateProcess is failing, and you're following it by closing two handles that were undoubtedly indeterminate values because of the failure.

Comment: `c:\firefox` isn't a file which you would see if you called `GetLastError` when `CreateProcess` failed and it returned 2.  The good news is `c:\firefox.bat` might be a file, so you should be launching that.  Depending on your OS, the permissions for the root directory of c are such that creating files there will fail unless you're running as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with this code. A few has already been pointed out in the comments (closing potentially invalid handles on failure, possibility that the batch file can't be created, and the rather questionable command line). Here's a few more issues.

First, you can't run a batch file this way.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `CreateProcess` clearly states:

> To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set *lpApplicationName* to cmd.exe and set *lpCommandLine* to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.

Second, you are passing a string literal for `lpCommandLine`, something that's also explicitly outlawed by the documentation:

> *lpCommandLine* [in, out, optional]
>
> ...
>
> The Unicode version of this function, **CreateProcessW**, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a **const** variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

Finally, why are you creating a temporary batch file to run a single command? You could easily have written the `CreateProcess` call to start Firefox directly.

Comment: The interesting, or maybe annoying, thing is that as long as you pass the full name of the batch file you don't seem to need cmd.exe.  If you do use cmd.exe in the application name parameter you need to fully qualify the path to it as the path will not be searched to find it.  If you use `cmd /c c:/whatever.bat` as the command line with the application name as NULL it will work too since that does search the path.  But yeah, I was thinking why the batch file as well.