# C++ CreateProcess - System Error #2 can't find file - what is wrong with my file path?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to open a PDF via Firefox with `CreateProcess()`, I am a beginner and know nothing about using `CreateProcess`, but in my last question someone pointed out the MSDN on it... it shows that:

```
To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; 
set lpApplicationName to    cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the 
following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.
```

Therefore I created a batch file that runs perfectly fine with the `system()` command, there are no problems with the batch file.

I can't figure out why the system can't find the file and I don't know if its the batch file, the exe in the batch file, the PDF doc in the batch file or the location of `cmd.exe`... Any help is greatly appreciated...

```
void openPDF(char scansQueue[][MAX_NAME], int index)
{
// build batch file
char openPath[300];
char procCommand[MAX_NAME]="C:\\firefox";
char cmdEXE[MAX_NAME]="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
fstream outfile;
outfile.open("C:\\firefox.bat");
copyCString(openPath,"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\"");
outfile << openPath;
outfile << ' ';
copyCString(openPath,"\"C:\\Scans\\");
catArray(openPath,scansQueue[index]);
catArray(openPath,"\"");

STARTUPINFOW si; 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; 
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
cout<<"PROCESS ATTEMPT"<<endl;
if(!CreateProcess((LPCTSTR)cmdEXE ,(LPWSTR)procCommand, NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))cout << GetLastError();cout<<"PROCESS FAILED TO EXECUTE!!!";
}
```

Comment: Casting is the wrong solution. Don't get rid of compiler errors, fix the problem.

Comment: Looks very similar to yesterday's question, with all the same problems and some new ones.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798403/trying-to-use-createprocess-no-compiler-errors-but-main-keeps-crashing

Comment: Try .bat on the end of 'procCommand', but more probably you will need "/c" in front of that as well.

Comment: The real question is why are you using a batch file for this when you can just launch firefox directly?

Comment: @chris - Are you talking about the LPWSTR or the LPCTSTR or both? From what I've read LPCTSTR returns a pointer to the character array, is that not what CreateProcess is waiting for? I think I recognize your name from a couple other questions I ask, and I thank you for your help

Comment: @RetiredNinja, First, I am using a batch file because the line I posted from the MSDN article was really the only configuration I understood enough to implement. Second, I have changed the file paths written to the batch file to reflect what would work in cmd. third, I am no longer passing a string literal as T.C. pointed out yesterday...

Comment: And yet you're still trying to launch the wrong filename.  Take what you're writing to the batch file and just pass that to CreateProcess.

Comment: pass it to the LPCTSTR parameter? or the LPWSTR parameter? and what would I put as the other? Thats essentially what I am asking

Comment: A LP*W*STR is a *wide*, i.e., Unicode string, and judging from this I'm assuming that you are compiling with UNICODE defined, which means that LPCTSTR == LPCWSTR. Both of your strings you passed to CreateProcess are strings of chars and not wchars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes the whole batch file thing is part of an XY problem, in that you don't really need to make a batch file, you really just want to launch Firefox with a command line parameter.

I also assume you don't really need to pass the whole array of filenames with an index for which to use, instead you should just pass the filename by itself as I did where I called the function.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void MsgBoxLastError()
{
    LPWSTR lpMsgBuf = NULL;
    if(FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        GetLastError(),
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPWSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL ) != 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, lpMsgBuf, L"Error", MB_OK);
    }
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}

void OpenWithFirefox(const char* Filename)
{
    const WCHAR pathToFirefox[] = L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe";
    const WCHAR scanPrefix[] = L"file://C:/Scans/";
    WCHAR fullCommandLine[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    //Build full command line
    swprintf_s(fullCommandLine, L"\"%s\" \"%s%S\"", pathToFirefox, scanPrefix, Filename);

    STARTUPINFOW si; 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; 
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    BOOL success = CreateProcess(NULL, fullCommandLine, NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    if(success)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    else
    {
        MsgBoxLastError();
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int MAX_NAME = 13;
    char scansQueue[][MAX_NAME] =
    {
        "file1.pdf",
        "file2.pdf"
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        OpenWithFirefox(scansQueue[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow awesome, it works! new issue arose though, is there a simple way to shift the focus back to the application window? It stays with the newly opened fire fox window until I click the application window... In any case, thank you thank you thank you

Comment: Telepathy is a very useful skill on StackOverflow `;-)`. I should start selling crystal balls. I'd make a fortune.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to keep focus without cooperation from the new process.  It's possible to ask that the new window doesn't activate itself in the startup info, but it doesn't appear to make any difference when used with Firefox.  Windows purposely makes it hard to steal focus from another window unless it has explicitly allowed you to do so.